# angularJS ng-repeat with filter for date greater than where date in array

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have looked a lot of places and cant seem to find what I am looking for.  It is probably simple but I am newer to angular and cant seem to figure it out.

The ng-repeat works fine as it is, but I want to filter out certain values.

I have a page with ng-repeat through data (see data object below) and I want to only include ones where current date > item value in array (date).

```
     vm.newsItems= [
       {
           ID: '1',
           date: '5/12/2016',
           newsTitle: 'This is news story header 1',
           newsText: 'This is news Story Text 1.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.'
       },
       {
           ID: '2',
           date: '5/30/2016',
           newsTitle: 'This is news story header 2',
           newsText: 'This is news Story Text 2.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.'
       }
```

code on page:

```
    <div class="box effect8" ng-repeat="newsItem in vm.newsItems">
                <h3>{{newsItem.newsTitle}}</h3>
                {{newsItem.newsText}}
            </div>
```

Comment: With current date I assume you mean today?

Comment: This can be done using `date` filter. but date parameter from your JSON object must be of type date of javascript.

Comment: @Yogesh The date filter is for formatting a `Date` display format, not for filtering out items in an array

Comment: Oops, Indeed you are correct @NexusDuck. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding a predicate with the [filter $filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) for filtering out the items:

`newsItem in vm.newsItems | filter: getItemsFromThePast()`

```
vm.getItemsFromThePast =  function(item) {
  var today = new Date();
  return item.date < today;
}
```

I'm assuming 2 things here:

- With *current date* you mean `new Date()`
- The property `date` of your objects are actual `Date` Objects, if they're date-formatted Strings you'll have to convert them to `Date` Objects first

Comment: #NexusDuck  Yes I meant new Date()  I updated my code (and added function to convert date) but the filter function is not being called.  I added an alert in there and it is not fireing so it is not getting called.  I included as you indicated but for some reason it is not hitting it.

Comment: It is still working meaning all the items in the object are being displayed, so that is still working just the filtering piece is never being called

Comment: Can you provide a plunkr /fiddle?

Comment: I am using single page app and have routing, I dont think so but could that be interferring?  I dont have anything with the same names anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Check [Codepen](http://codepen.io/chiragshah_mb/pen/MeWWBW?editors=1011). This will work for you. I have converted the date string to Object and used it with filter

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

 myApp.controller('MyController', function ($scope) {

 $scope.newsItems= [
   {
       ID: '1',
       date: '5/12/2016',
       newsTitle: 'This is news story header 1',
       newsText: 'Some text.'
   },
   {
       ID: '2',
       date: '5/30/2016',
       newsTitle: 'This is news story header 2',
       newsText: 'Some text.'
   }
];

 angular.forEach($scope.newsItems, function(value,key) {
  value.date = new Date(value.date);
 });

 $scope.filterDate =  function(newsItem) {
  var today = new Date();   
  return newsItem.date < today;
 }
```

});